# JSON-LD makes website result with no thumbnail in Mobile Search

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, json-ld, search-results, thumbnail

I saw that it was picking one of the images from my portfolio, so I planned to add explicitly one image for Google Mobile Search result to pick up using JSON-LD tags.

A funny thing is that, it says the following issues:

- We do not detect any structured data on your site.
- We did not find any rich card structured data on your website.

My website is a personal website, which is `"@type": "person"` and my full JSON-LD looks like this:

```
<!-- JSON-LD Markup -->
<script type='application/ld+json'> 
{
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "person",
  "name": "Praveen Kumar Purushothaman",
  "jobTitle": "Cook, Cat Lover, Front End Architect, Web Developer Evangelist & Cloud Computing Consultant",
  "url": "https://praveen.science/",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "Camborne",
    "addressRegion": "Cornwall",
    "addressCountry": "United Kingdom"
  },
  "image": "https://i.imgur.com/IjdZYJVm.jpg"
}
</script>
```

I believe I have specific everything right. I am not sure what's happening, but it shows this way in mobile:

[image: preview of mobile]

At least last time it was showing an image like this:

[image: wrogn pic]

But what I am expecting is Google should show [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wmrG.jpg):

[image: expected one]

Would appreciate any guidance to making this work, thanks.

Comment: `We do not detect any structured data on your site.` Simple, you haven't waited a few months for those to be reported by Google Search Console. Changes to rich snippets can take several months to either appear or update in the search results. Test your code using Rich Snippet testing tool and then just wait.

Comment: @SimonHayter Nopes! [**Google's cache**](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://praveen.science/&num=1&strip=0&vwsrc=1) shows the JSON-LD! Duh.

Comment: Google Cache has nothing to do with Google Search Console duh, they do not communicate with one another, they work independently from one another duh. So Rich Snippets has nothing to do with Google Cache, Indexing has nothing to do With Google Cache and GSC has nothing to do with Google Cache. All you need to know is that Google is very slow at updating its 'Rich Data', if you changed something, test it with Rich Snippet Testing Tool, then wait 2-8 weeks for those to be reflected in GSC, they might appear in search results faster than they appear in GSC... because GSC/Cache is not realtime.

Comment: @SimonHayter Thanks man. Didn't know this. I thought they are all the same. **But how did it change immediately when I added the JSON-LD?** The wrong thumbnail disappeared! `:(` At least I had a thumbnail. Do you have an answer for this and also please send me the link to Rich Snippet Testing Tool. Thanks man.

Comment: @SimonHayter Is my JSON-LD implementation right? Also why did you remove the concerned link to my website? (ps: I am not new to Stack Exchange, check out my Stack Overflow profile). `:)`

Comment: The link was removed because there's no need for the link to answer your question.

Comment: @SimonHayter It's been more than a year...  No updates in the Google cache. You can have a quick look yourself.

Comment: I was just waiting for this till date. It's been more than 2 years of same code and this isn't working. So I request someone to help me or at least reopen this question, as this is not a dupe of the other question.

Comment: You flagged to re-open this, however it looks like a duplicate to me because the error message you are getting matches.   Are you still getting that error message?  If not, edit your question to remove it.   Have you tried the structured data testing tool from Google?   If so, edit your question to put in the results from that tool.  The way to get a question re-opened is to edit it and differentiate it from the duplicate.   After you have done so, you can flag it for moderator review.

Comment: I don't think Google is giving out icons based on authorship anymore, so the Person schema isn't going to produce a rich snippet now.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for the explanation, so is there anything that I can do at the moment?  To make this work? It is perfectly detecting the JSON LD (check https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fpraveen.science%2F).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Let me do it again. What scheme do you suggest other than Person schema then? Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: The [search gallery](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery) shows all the rich snippets that are available.   There may not be any that are available for your site.   I don't have any for any of my sites.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for your help... This should be enough. In case of any further questions or clarification, I'll ask for a new question. You have done a great help! 